# Switch props from redux and react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have prop pass to my component. That prop can come from **redux** or from **parent component**. I use `mergeProp`(react-redux) to switch them. But I confuse about it. I want know this is good for performance or not because my code logic need switch prop like that. Thank for your help.

Here is my code

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  myProp: state.myProp,
  otherProp: state.otherProp,
});

const mergeProp = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => {
  return {
    ...ownProps,
    ...dispatchProps,
    ...stateProps,
    myProp: ownProps.myCondition
      ? stateProps.myProp
      : ownProps.myProp,
  }
}
```

When using

```
// use myProp from redux
<MyComponent myProp="prop ignore" myCondition={true} />

// use myProp from ownProps
<MyComponent myProp="prop pass from parent component" myCondition={false} />
```